# Jmeter: Constant throughput timer value change for every five mins

Tags: javascript, jmeter, stress-testing, beanshell

IN JMETER:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer

It has mentioned that constant throughput variable value can be changed using a `JavaScript or BeanShell function to provide a changing value`.

I have a requirement that in ultimate thread group , constant throughput value needs to be changed for every 5 mins using beanshell pre-processor.

for ex.Target throughput should

1. start with 4000 samples per min, hold the load for 5 mins
2. ramp up to 5000 samples per min and hold the load for 5 mins
3. ramp up to 6000 samples per min and so on up to 20000 samples per min.

Kindly share your ideas or work around for this question.

This is break point performance test so we doing this type of approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) would be much easier to use, example configuration would look like:

[image: JMeter Throughput Shaping Timer]

You can install Throughput Shaping Timer (and keep it up-to-date) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Throughput Shaping Timer]

---

Make sure you have enough threads under Thread Group to generate the desired throughput as timer can only pause the threads to limit JMeter to certain RPS value, it won't kick off extra threads if there will be a lack

Comment: okay thanks @dmitri .  But can we place constant throughput timer and throughput shaping timer in one thread group?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I wouldn't mix them as it may lead to unexpected behavior

Comment: Okay @dmitri. Let me disable CTT & use TST only. can we place throughput shaping timer  and throughput controller in one ultimate thread group. i have 84 endpoints, each endpoints achieve difference tps for one hour test duration.

Comment: Throughput Shaping Timer should follow the same [JMeter Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) as the [Contant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) (as well as other Test Elements)